# iMac - Install XP Can't Set Primary Display on the Second Monitor

Tags: imac, display, windows

I installed XP SP3 in iMac 17 inch (Late 2006), also installed all drivers from BootCamp 2.0 drivers bundle, all works fine. The question is, I have two displays, and the video card of this iMAc is ATI X1600 mobile, it's able to set the external display to be the primary one (I did it on OS X), I checked the display setting in XP, for the second display, the checkbox is gray so it's unable to set to primary one.

I googled a lot also, seems all solution mentioned it should install the full-ATI drivers (includes control panel), but I didn't find any place to download this driver for iMac, I did download some drivers for XP, but it's not working.

I am thinking if there are some ways to set the external display to be primary, by using software or some tools else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution, go to AMD boot camp driver page, and download the panel, install it with .NET 2.0 (I forgot this, so always wrong), then set primary display in panel.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/bootcamp-xp.aspx